# Where is the memory issue in my map?

Tags: c++

I was loading data from database and inserting it into a map. When I tried to print the map size and data, it still shows size 1 and only the last row prints. All previous data is overwritten and contains last value. Any pointer in this
issue. I have changed variable names because of a company issue.

I have done some check Point also. All key values are unique.

```
typdef long_char char[38];

for(int j = 0; j < 31; j++)
{
    sample_enum param_sub_type = result_set[j];
    long_char param_name;

    strncpy(param_name,result_set[j], sizeof(param_name));
    input_status_cd.insert(std::pair<long_char,sample_enum>(param_name, param_sub_type));      

    /*Insert Into Map */    <I suspect this may be issue but not sure>
}

/*Printing Size of map */
input_status_sd::size_type input_status_cd_size;
etlog_msg(intput_status_cd_size :] [%d]",intput_status_cd.size());
```

Comment: Please note that `strncpy` will **not** add the terminating `'\0'` to `param_name` if it copies the full length. If you wan't to use `param_name` as a string, use `strncpy(param_name, result_set[j], sizeof(param_name) - 1); param_name[sizeof(param_name) - 1] = '\0';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `long_char` is defined as `char[38]` so when you insert into the map it will use try to use `operator<` which will result in comparing the address of the first char of the array. Since you are creating this array in the loop, most probably the same stack frame gets allocated so the address of the first char remains same for every object. Hence all the previous data gets overwritten as the `map` thinks that you are inserting the same object again. The simplest way to solve this would be to use `std::string` as a typedef for `long_char`.

Comment: Thanks for you input . But is it possible to use same code with some modification. bit silly for stick same code. But most of code is delivered into production and want minimal code changes. If i implement than I have to do chnages in lot of places.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `std::map<std::string,sample_enum>` instead of a `std::map<long_char,sample_enum>`. In this way, the `operator<` of `std::string` will work as intended (lexicographically compare). With `std::string` you must not use `strncmp` to copy the string buy you have to use the assignment operator.